# JAVA Crear atributo int y devolver en metodo get string

Tags: java

Estoy con una tarea y no logro poder hacerla.
En el enunciado dice tal que así:

'Algunos atributos tendrán un valor que se definirá al instanciarse el objeto y ya nunca modificarán su contenido durante toda la vida del objeto (constantes). Podría decirse que definen algo así como la naturaleza inmutable:

código del teatro;
nombre del teatro;
aforo del teatro.

**Los códigos de los teatros serán consecutivos y comenzarán por 1. Cada vez que se instancie un nuevo objeto Teatro se le asignará un nuevo código que no podrá volver a ser utilizado nunca más, aunque ese objeto dejara de utilizarse y desapareciera. La representación interna de los códigos podrá implementarse como se considere oportuno, lo único que habrá que tener en cuenta es que el método getter que lo devuelva lo hará en forma de String.**

Y luego me piden hacer un get del código. Mi duda es en la declaración lo pongo como int? como string? hago el código consecutivo en el getCodigo? Muchas gracias y un saludo.

Dejo parte del código

```
  //Atributos de clase variables (representan informacion de la clase)

private static int NumeroTeatros;                         //Numero de teatros instanciados
private static int CantidadObras;                         //Cantidad total de obras activas que se estan representando
private static int EntradasVendidasTotales;              //Cantidad de entradas vendidas en todos los teatros y todas las funciones


//Atributos de objeto
// -----------------------


// Atributos de objeto constantes (representan características inmutables)
private final int codigoTeatro;                         // Codigo del teatro
private final String NombreTeatro;                         // Nombre del teatro    
private final int Aforo;
```

Y aqui el get

```
//Metodos de consulta
   
   
   
   public String getCodigoTeatro(){
    
       
       for (int numero= 0; numero<100; numero++){
         
       String suma = "" + numero;}
       
       codigoTeatro = String suma;
       
       return this.codigoTeatro;
   
   }
   
   public String getNombreTeatro(){
       return this.NombreTeatro; 
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que tener algo como esto:

```
public class Teatro {
  private static int CodigoActual =0; //Esto es una variable estatica es comun para todas las instancias de la clase teatro
  
  public int Codigo; //es el código individual de cada instancia de teatro
  public Teatro(){
      this.Codigo = ++CodigoActual; //se asigna un código correlativo e incremental cada vez que se instancia un teatro
  }
  
  public String getCodigoTeatro(){ //retorna el código como string
      return this.Codigo + "";
  }
}
```

Comment: A la hora de crear getTeatrosTotales me da 0. Cual es la suma o el contador que tengo que poner o crear?

Comment: `CodigoActual` tiene la cantidad de creados, basta poner Teatro.CodigoActual y te dará la cantidad que es igual al último id (ya que es un número correlativo)

Comment: Muchas gracias Yussef! Solucionado, un abrazo